# Can one detect system language change in Electron?

Tags: electron

Currently using [getPreferredSystemLanguages()](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/app#appgetpreferredsystemlanguages) to detect system language.

Is there a way to detect when user changes system language to switch app locale (using [i18next](https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18next) and [react-i18next](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-i18next) to handle localization)?